# How to json_decode invalid json?

Tags: php, json

example.php

```
{"status": "ok"} {"status": "error"}
```

result:

```
ok , error
```

My website is showing a blank page(I'm using this code),can you help me to fix it?

```
<?php
$userinfo = 'example.php';
$fgc = file_get_contents($userinfo);
$json2 = json_decode($fgc, true);
$media = $json2['status'];

$mediaId = $media;

echo $mediaId;
?>
```

Comment: You may have to use the fully qualified path for example.php. E.g if `example.php` is in the root directory (ie `public_html`) then `$userinfo = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/example.php';` may resolve your issue

Comment: You should enable error reporting: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` after `<?php`

Comment: In fact, my problem is in {"status": "ok"} {"status": "error"}, because there is no comma separating them

Comment: As robbie says, that's not valid JSON, either complain to the source or `str_replace("} {", "},{", $fgc)` with a risk at using the latter

Comment: it's not safe, but if your JSON is literally as small as what you have provided, that str replace will give you valid JSON

Comment: $fgc = file_get_contents($userinfo);
$ber = str_replace("} {", "},{", $fgc);
$json2 = json_decode($ber, true); ??

Comment: correct, is that working for you?

Comment: yassss, i will result show "ok & error" ,can you give me the code?

Comment: There you go, see my answer - should get you back on the right track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will resolve your issue in the non-recommended way:

```
$broken_json = '{"success": "ok"} {"success": "error"}';
$fixed_json = "[" . str_replace("} {", "},{", $broken_json) . "]";
echo $fixed_json;

$array = json_decode($fixed_json, true);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Result:

```
[{"success": "ok"},{"success": "error"}]

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["success"]=>
    string(2) "ok"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["success"]=>
    string(5) "error"
  }
}
```

Recommended Way:

Actually get VALID JSON from the source

Answer (score 1):

example.php does not contain valid JSON

Here's probably what you want:

```
 [ {"status": "ok"} , {"status": "error"} ]
```

You can validate JOSN here: http://jsonlint.com/

You can find more on how to debug PHP "white screen of death" here: [PHP's white screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death) (read the top two answers)

Comment: I took the results of external websites, and as a result there is no comma separating between it.

Comment: Just because you got it from an external website does not mean it's right. It's NOT valid JSON, therefore `json_decode` WILL fail and throw an error and give you a white screen.

Comment: @ALFIANANANDAPUTRA then contact whoever made this external website and tell him to learn the basics of what he's supposed to do, because that was **not** valid JSON.